# Are the chances between the Portable Slots and the Slot Machine different?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I just found an item called Portable Slots, which allowed me to use it (with <kbd>spacebar</kbd>) any number of times (regardless of charges), but it took a coin on every use, like the normal slot machine.

I used it something like fifteen times and only won something about three times, which seems substantially worse than the normal Slot Machine.

Are the odds when using the Portable Slots different than the normal Slot Machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chances are in fact the same, as far as anyone can tell.  I've encountered it twice and have been quite lucky with it.